# $ABCD$ is a rectangle and $E,F,G,H$ are any points on sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$, respectively. Show that $EF+FG+GH+HE>\sqrt{2} AC$.

Tags: geometry

$ABCD$ is a rectangle and $E,F,G,H$ are any points on sides $AB,BC,CD,DA$, respectively. Show that $EF+FG+GH+HE>\sqrt{2} AC$. Is it true for all quadrilaterals $ABCD$?

[image]

Comment: I edited your question and added a picture. If incorrect, let me know.

Comment: Could you use the fact that (ef)+(fg)+(hg)+(he) <=4AC?

Comment: @EmmadKareem Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** "straighten" the $e\to f\to g\to h$ path by considering a reflection with respect to the $BC$ side, bringing $A$ to $A'$, $D$ to $D'$, then a reflection with respect to the $CD'$ side, bringing $B$ to $B''$ and $A'$ to $A''$, then a reflection with respect to the $D'A''$ side. Consider that the shortest path between two fixed points is the segment joining them.

[image]